# Using a dynamic variable binding in a leiningen plugin

Tags: plugins, clojure, leiningen, clojure.test

I’ve got a lein plugin that manually runs my clojure.test code.  It declares a dynamic variable `baseuri` that I wish to access from within my tests.  I’ll strip out and change the code to get straight to the point.  Here, inside of my plugin, I have a config file that creates the dynamic `baseuri` variable and sets it to a blank string.

```
;; myplugin
;; src/myplugin/config.clj
(ns leiningen.myplugin.config)    
(def ^:dynamic baseuri "")
```

A task from within the plugin sets the dynamic `baseuri` variable and runs tests with clojure.test:

```
;; src/myplugin/runtests.clj
(ns leiningen.myplugin.runtests
      (:require [leiningen.myplugin.config :as config]
                [clojure.test]
                [e2e.sometest]))

(defn run [project]
  (binding [config/baseuri "https://google.com/"]
    (println config/baseuri) ;; <-- prints google url
    ;; run clojure.test test cases from e2e.sometest namespace
    ;; This will call the `sampletest` test case
    (clojure.test/run-tests e2e.sometest)
  ))
```

And inside of my clojure.test I try to use the baseuri variable but the binding doesn’t hold.  It’s value is what I originally declared `baseuri` to be (an empty string)

```
;; tests/e2e/sometest.clj
(ns e2e.sometest
  (:require [leiningen.myplugin.config :as config]))

(deftest sampletest
  (println config/baseuri))  ;; <-- Prints an empty string instead of google url
```

I've edited the code to show in a basic manner how the clojure.test cases are run.  I simply pass in the namespace I want to be run to the `clojure.test/run-tests` method.

Comment: Could you show us what code is exactly in place of your comment `;; runs clojure.test code here`?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how the clojure.test test cases get run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that `clojure.test` implementation is not optimal when it comes to parameterising your tests.

I am not sure why your `binding` form doesn't work - I have checked the code in `clojure.test` and I cannot see what could be wrong. I would check if:

- the tests get executed in the same thread as the `binding` is established (maybe you could add logging the thread name/id in your plugin and in your tests)
- different class loaders causing that your plugin namespace and its global dynamic variable is actually loaded and defined twice

I have one more idea (and I really don't want to criticise your solution, just trying to find alternative solutions :)): your problem is to pass a global configuration options to your code under test from external sources like test scripts configuration. Have you thought about passing them as environment variables? You could easily read them using `(System/getenv "baseuri")` or [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ).

Comment: Thank you for providing more background and details in your question. I have edited my answer. I am sorry if you felt my previous answer was not sympathetic, I was just trying to be helpful.

Comment: You were correct.  In my `project.clj` file I have added the plugin to the `:plugins` map key.  Also, in order to be able to `(require)` the plugin config from the application I must also declare the plugin in the `:dependencies` map key.  Thus it is getting loaded twice, just as you thought.  Thank you, Piotrek, for your time on this one.  Very very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a dynamic var for very specific reasons, but, as you do not state so explicitly, I take a shot here.

Avoid dynamic rebinding of vars. At its best case, avoid global state at all, instead redefine your functions to take the baseuri as a parameter.
Or refactor your application to not have the need for static vars at all, like you have it right now.

**EDIT** My guess is that your functions:

```
(defn run [project]
  (binding [config/baseuri "https://google.com/"]
    (println config/baseuri) ;; <-- prints google url
    ;; runs clojure.test code here …
  ))

(deftest sampletest
  (println config/baseuri))
```

are not connected in any way. At least I dont see how they should be. You are running a test and print some other var without rebinding it.
Maybe you could add a link to a repo to a minimal reproducable testcase to understand it better?

Comment: Hey sveri, I agree.  Unfortunately, do to the enormous limitations of `clojure.test` it simply is not possible to pass parameters to tests written with `deftest`.  I've found that very little of `clojure.test` allows functional programming which ties my hands behind my back.  If `deftest` allowed arguments I'd be set.

Comment: It is hard to tell. still:
1. reconfigure your application, it just looks wrong
2. `binding` only rebinds in its local scope, as soon as you leave the `binding`scope `baseuri` will be `""` again.